# Grid of magick images in R

Tags: r, imagemagick

Goal here is to have images set up in a grid-like fashion using magick read and annotated images. I can get the images read, annotated, and in the groups of 3 (i.e. 3 columns). I just can't figure out how to stack the groups together.
This is the desired result, but isn't flexible (?) and image_ggplot() is painfully slow:

```
grid.arrange(image_ggplot(annotated_images[[1]]),image_ggplot(annotated_images[[2]]),
             image_ggplot(annotated_images[[3]]),image_ggplot(annotated_images[[4]]),
             image_ggplot(annotated_images[[5]]),image_ggplot(annotated_images[[6]]),
             image_ggplot(annotated_images[[7]]),image_ggplot(annotated_images[[8]]),
             image_ggplot(annotated_images[[9]]),image_ggplot(annotated_images[[10]]),
             image_ggplot(annotated_images[[11]]),ncol=3)
```

Here's my attempt to build it up from ground:

```
newlogo <- image_read("https://jeroen.github.io/images/Rlogo.png")
images=rep(newlogo,11)
chunk_images=split(images, ceiling(seq_along(images)/3))
annotated_images=lapply(images,function(x){
  image_annotate(image_read("https://jeroen.github.io/images/Rlogo.png"), paste0('Random Number: ',rnorm(1)), color = 'white',boxcolor='grey10', size = 23)
})
list_of_rows=lapply(chunk_images,function(x){image_append(c(image_annotate(x, paste0('Random Number: ',rnorm(1)), color = 'white',boxcolor='grey10', size = 23)))})
#list_of_rows[1] == 3 images side-by-side
#list_of_rows[2] == 3 images side-by-side
#list_of_rows[3] == 3 images side-by-side
#list_of_rows[4] == the remaining 2 images
```

I want to stack the `list_of_rows` on top of each other, neither of these are working:

```
lapply(list_of_rows,function(x){image_append(x,stack=T)})
do.call(c,list_of_rows)
```

Just looking for a flexible way to arrange anywhere from 4-32 images in the number of columns I can control (won't know the total number of images each time).

Comment: You can stack using the equivalent of -append or -smush or make a grid using montage.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments by @fmw42, you can control the column arrangement using the function `image_montage` and the [tile parameter](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/magick.pdf)

```
newlogo <- "https://jeroen.github.io/images/Rlogo.png"
images=rep(newlogo,11)
img <- magick::image_read(images) %>%
  magick::image_montage(tile = '3')
```